# How to create a rounded title border in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I do understand that to create a title border, you do something like:

```
BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("  Your Title  ");
```

However this creates a rectangle border whereas I need a rectangle with curved corners.

Now from what I understand you can create your own custom border by:

```
class CustomBorder implements Border
{
  ...
}
```

The problem is that I'm not sure how to write the code that overrides the method:

```
public void paintBorder(Component component, Graphics g, int x, int y, int width, int height)
```

Or better yet, is there a way to do it without implementing your own Border class? And if not, how would you write that custom Title Border? I'm ok with drawing a rectangle with rounded corners, but how do you do it so that there's space for the label too?

Comment: Please ignore this question. Once you create a RounderBorder class, Swing will remove the border under the title text for you.

Comment: Actually ignore my last comment. It only does this if you use  BorderFactory to create your border, such as a LineBorder. Guess it's time to look at how LineBorder does it's painting...

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to create a title border with rounded edges without implementing your own Border class. Simply pass a rounded border to TitledBorder's constructor. Try the following:

```
LineBorder roundedLineBorder = new LineBorder(Color.black, 5, true);
TitledBorder roundedTitledBorder = new TitledBorder(roundedLineBorder, "Title");
```

Answer (score 3):

Although this thread is a bit old already, maybe someone who stumbles over it might find the solution useful:

You can add a title to any border you want:

1. implement your custom border class `public class MyBorder extends AbstractBorder {...` and in the `public void paintBorder(Component c, Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h)`
   method you can paint your own custom border on the Graphics context
2. create an instance of this custom border

   ```
   Border myborder = new MyBorder();
   ```
3. create the TitledBorder using your custom border as a template and add it to the object you want (in this case a JPanel:

   ```
   jPanel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(myborder , "Border title"));
   ```

You should now see your custom Border and above that the Title with the default settings of the Look&Feel you are using.