# Set the JPanel size to fill parent with little margin

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, dynamic-sizing

I have two Jpanel (**JpanelLeft** and **JpanelLeftContent**) how can i make the JpanelLeftContent  fill parent size with a little margin on the left an right side. i have tried different layout and tried to modify the hgap and vgap values, but none of them give me a good result.

```
  JPanel JpanelLeft = new JPanel();
  JPanel JpanelLeftContent = new JPanel();
  JpanelLeft.add(JpanelLeftContent);
```

And if possible how can i make the JpanelLeftContent look like a rounded rectangle as shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056089/how-to-create-a-rounded-title-border-in-java-swing or http://www.javafaq.nu/java-example-code-800.html

Comment: What is your JRE version, in 1.7 you can do that with a built in function (rounded rectangle) ?

Comment: Here is the link I forgot to add that before [Rounded Rectangle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createLineBorder(java.awt.Color, int, boolean))

Comment: @IMAnis_tn : You are MOST Welcome and KEEP SMILING :-), though 1.7 has many bugs, which might can give weird behaviour at many times :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at how `Border`s work. Especially 
[`BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(int top, int left, int bottom, int right)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/BorderFactory.html#createEmptyBorder%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) might be helpfull.

Answer (score 4):

> ..how can i make the JpanelLeftContent look like a rounded rectangle as shown in the picture.

See [`TextBubbleBorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8463742/418556) for a start.

[image]

Obviously you'd need to remove the little `v` at the bottom, & shove the bottom border further down.  The code is not comprehensively tested, and will require further tweaks and fixes.  'Batteries not included'.

Comment: @nIcEcOw As is yours +1'able (already done earlier).  I suspect it gets around some of the problems (using insets) that my approach might suffer.

Comment: But using JRE 1.7, one can never say, what more bugs one will bring up, as same thingy do persists with this thing too, on horizontal resize LOL :(

Answer (score 3):

Do try this code example :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class InsetTesting extends JFrame
{
    private void createAndDisplayGUI()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationByPlatform(true);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setOpaque(true);
        contentPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(
                                    Color.DARK_GRAY.darker(), 5, true));
        contentPane.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        add(contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public Insets getInsets()
    {
        return (new Insets(30, 20, 10, 20));
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return (new Dimension(200, 400));
    }

    public static void main(String\u005B\u005D args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                new InsetTesting().createAndDisplayGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the output of the same :

[image: INSETS]

Answer (score 2):

To make a JPanel appear rounded, you need to make your own class that extends JPanel, override paintComponent and draw the panel as an ellipse [Javadoc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Ellipse2D.html) This will create a customized object which is an JPanel.

When you specify the size of your ellipse, you want to get the Y and X values from the parent panel (since you will be adding your ellipse ontop of another panel) and then subtract the number of pixels you desire from the X-axis. This could be achived by passing those values to the "ellipse panel" constructor.

Comment: But when re-sizing the parent Panel dos the JpanelLeftContent re-size too ? should i override the repaint method also ?

Comment: You could set the "new" values to the ellipse panel with a setter and simply call repaint

Comment: *"you need to make your own class that extends JPanel"*  Not necessarily.  I think a border is a better strategy to pursue for this functionality.  See my answer.